# how delete object in djago with yes no in sweetify

Tags: python, django

I want to delete the desired object with the help of the sweetify package when the user presses the  yes button, but nothing happens. Does anyone know the reason? How can I fix it?? This is the code
`

```
class DeleteOrder(DeleteView):
    model = OrderDetail
    template_name = 'dashboard/dashboard_order_list.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard_user:order-list')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            sweetify_response = sweetify.sweetalert(request, 'آیا مطمٔنید؟', text="آیا واقعا میخواهید سفارش مورد نظر حذف شود؟", persistent='بله حذف کن', cancel='نه بمونه', dangerMode=True, timer=15000, focusConfirm=True, confirmButtonText='حذف', cancelButtonText='انصراف', showCancelButton=True)
            if sweetify_response.get('did_confirm'):
                messages.success(request, 'سفارش مورد نظر با موفقیت حذف شد') 
                response = super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
                return response
            elif sweetify_response.get('did_cancel'):
                return redirect(self.success_url)
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'سفارش مورد نظر حذف نشد')
                return redirect(self.success_url)
        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, str(e))
            return redirect(self.success_url)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.object.get_absolute_url()
`
```

First, I tried to delete the object without checking, which was deleted before the user confirmed the object, but then I changed the code so that it checks the button that the user pressed and then deletes it, but nothing happens. I tried a lot, but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: Are you sure that the "confirm" request is a POST request?

Comment: yes It will be deleted without using sweetify